# Css files doesn't load using proxy in Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have these lines in my nginx config:

location /proxy {

```
proxy_pass http://mysite.ru/;
proxy_redirect http://localhost/app http://mysite.ru/app;
```

}

Css files from mysite.ru are located in app folder, but it can't be loaded because full path to css file is like this: `http://mysite.ru/app/files/css/style.css` and it hasn't `proxy` in path, so it's trying to load `http://localhost/app/files/css/style.css`, and in the second line I'm trying to redirect this, but nothing works, what means that I'm doing something wrong (I don't know much about Nginx, what I'm trying is to understand)

Comment: `proxy_redirect` only works with 3xx redirection. It sounds like the links embedded in your html pages is wrong. You should fix the app. Nginx has limited support for rewriting links using [`sub_filter`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter), but the best solution is to fix the app.

Comment: Wow, `sub_filter` helped me, thanks! The app was correct, if I request `http://mysite.ru/app/files/css/style.css` it opens without errors, so I think I can use `sub_filter`.